# Passing and using props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I had the following

```
const Obj = [
     {
          name: 'a'
     },
     {
          name: 'b'
     }
]

const RenderSomeObj = props => {
     console.log('props', props)
     return null
}
```

When I go to render it with

```
{Obj.map((item, index) => (
    <RenderSomeObj props={item} />
))
```

It comes out as props: props: {}. how can I get it as just the object that is item like props: { name: 'a'}? eg.

I want props to be

```
     {
          name: 'a'
     }

not

     props: {...}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the spread operator.

```
{Obj.map((item, index) => (
    <RenderSomeObj {...item} />
))
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the attribute `props` is regarded as a JSX attribute.
Please take a look on the [react-native documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

> When React sees an element representing a user-defined component, it passes JSX attributes and children to this component as a single object. We call this object “props”.

In here

```
const RenderSomeObj = props => {
     console.log('props', props)
     return null
}
```

`props` is the single object of the JSX attributes and children to this component.

Therefore, to get what you want, simply modify your component as below

```
 const RenderSomeObj = props => {
     console.log('props', props.props)
     return null
  }
```